# loading a returned value from php into a js variable using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically all i wanna do is something like this.

```
var myVar = $.load("phpscript.php","var=one");
```

phpscript.php

```
<?
$a = $_GET['var'];
if($a == "one") { return 1 };
else return false;
?>
```

Right now i am doing this the most idiotic way as i cannot find out how to do this the proper way. what i am doing currently is making my phpscript return a hidden field with the value

```
return "<input type='hidden' value='1' id='takeValueFromThisID>";
```

into a div from the calling page and finally use the above id to retrieve the value. Even though this works its very idiotic. Can some one pls guide me in the right way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get("phpscript.php", { 'var': 'one' }, function(resp) {
    alert(resp); // '1'

});
```

and a test PHP script:

```
<?php
    echo '1';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP Code

```
<?
    $a = $_GET['var'];
    if($a == 'one') {
        echo 1
    } else {
        echo 0; // or '' may be?
    }
?>
```

## AJAX

```
var myVar;
$.get("phpscript.php", {"var": "one"}, function (resp) {
  myVar = resp;
});
```

The problem here is that myVar will be `"1"` or whatever *after* the AJAX request is completed. This may take a couple of milliseconds (or seconds). If you plan to use `myVar` in your script you must wait until it becomes something other than `undefined`.